# Dissolution of protein powder in water

Tags: physical-chemistry, food-chemistry

I am using this [Mocha Coffe](https://www.optimumnutrition.com/en_US/products/amino-energy/strength-and-recovery#sePr0HZkOig3ZCxP.97).

When I try to dissolve it in a cupful of cold water, it forms a globule of powder and does not dissolve.

But if I add a small amount of water to the powder and mix it, it makes a paste which will dissolve in more water. What is happening here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of powders show this behaviour. Try it with flour or 100% cocoa powder, and you get the same result.

What all these powders have in common, is that the grains contain some hydrophobic material.

When you put a bunch of powder in water, the outside layer of powder gets wet and sticks together, but doesn't let the water through, trapping an air bubble inside. Then when you try to stir, the waterproof bubbles just float around, easily avoiding your spoon.

But if you only put a small amount of liquid, the stirring is much better, and you can wet all the grains.

Source: [this entry](https://h2g2.com/approved_entry/A317134) in the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (of all places).